# Prevent the vertex normals from being recalculated when a skeletal mesh is deformed?

Tags: shaders, skeletal-animation, normals, unreal-5

I am trying to create a game with stylized shading like Arc System Works Style, which requires the normals to be edited by hand (I do so in Blender). However, after importing to Unreal Engine, these normals would become deformed and ugly when the mesh is deformed through a skeleton.

In Unity there is an option for "no recalculation on deform," which prevents this issue as the vertex normals are not changed upon deformation.

Is there any way to do this in Unreal Engine 5, either by modifying the engine itself or any type of shader work?

Comment: One thing you could try is saving your normals as vertex colours, to "hide" them from the skinning transformation.

Comment: @DMGregory how would I use the vertex colors to plug back into the shader as a normal direction? I would need the vertex normals to dictate the normals to make the shading stylized and clean.

Comment: You would read the vertex colour, then use it as a normal vector instead of a colour. Any part of the shader that accepts a normal, use this colour-derived normal instead.